# PHP - Which conditional test to use?

Tags: php, if-statement

Are those 2 expressions equivalent (I mean "can I replace the 1st one with the 2nd one):

```
if ($var) { ... }
```

and

```
if (!empty($var)) { ... }
```

I feel there is a difference but I rationally cannot say which one.

For me the first one evaluates if $var is true or false and I may be wrong but "false" evaluations means that $var is false (boolean), empty (string, object or array), 0 value (int, float or string) or undefined ... that's the way the "empty" function works (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

If those tests are equivalent (at least in specific cases), which is better to use (readability, performance, maintenance, ...)?

Thanks

Comment: first one is check variable and second one is used for array

Comment: @RaviChauhan lol, wut?

Comment: @RaviChauhan: not agreed with u

Comment: @RaviChauhan you're wrong: empty() isn't limited to arrays. You can test emptiness of a var as explained in PHP documentation.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They differ in that for your second example, `$var` doesn't have to be set before using it. In the first case, if `$var` isn't set, a notice will be generated, while in the second example, it won't.

This can be useful for values submitted by users inside the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals (.. and for `$_COOKIE` and `$_SERVER`).

```
// will generate a notice if there is no `foo` in the query string
if ($_GET['foo'])

// will not generate a notice, even if the key is not set
if (!empty($_GET['foo']))
```

Comment: You're right, I was wondering if the 2nd expression could replace the 1st one (because 1st one is used in our actual code) without side effect because we a lot of "unreadable" code (>400 lines methods, vars that are implicitly casted between string, int, array in the same method, ...) and I try to make it more maintainable without breaking anything else ('cause of course there's no test at all, nor functional nor unit nor UX)

Answer (score 1):

```
!empty($var)
```

Determine whether a variable is considered to be not empty. A variable is considered not empty if it `does exist` or if its value equals `TRUE`. **empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.**

```
if ($var) { ... }
```

You'll test if $var contains a value that's not false -- 1 is true, 123 is too

*Extra:*

```
isset($var)
```

Using isset(), you'll test if a variable has been set -- i.e. if any not-null value has been written to it.

### -

It all depends on what you want to check/test. I do hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps 'cause in my context $var is always defined but your answer can be useful for other people

Answer (score 1):

empty() -> If variable not exist or its equals to false empty function returns true.

Imagine that you did not declare $var

```
if ($var) { 
    echo '1'; 
} 
else { 
    echo '2'; 
}
```

Output will be:

> NOTICE Undefined variable: var on line number *

If you use empty:

```
if (!empty($var)) { 
    echo 1; 
}
else { 
    echo 2; 
}
```

Output will be:

> 2

Also the following values are considered to be empty

```
$var = 0;
$var = "";
$var = false;
$var = null;
```

Also check isset() function [Php.net isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: In a well-formed code notices (warning, errors, ...) should never be used to by-pass parts of code but I've already read code like that. I may be wrong but I think that "1" could be echoed depending on PHP ini value for reporting.